# How to chain custom_targets from different directories in CMake without global variables?

Tags: cmake

According to this tutorial (Part 5):

https://samthursfield.wordpress.com/2015/11/21/cmake-dependencies-between-targets-and-files-and-custom-commands/

> File-level dependencies of custom targets are not propagated

So when I have two custom targets in chain, second custom command should depend both on **first custom target** and **first custom command output**

But what if I have custom targets in different sub-directories. How can I get path to files generated by first target?

```
project
├── gen1
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
├── gen2
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
└── CMakeLists.txt
```

gen1 CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(SPECIAL_TEXT foo)    
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT gen1
    COMMAND cmake -E echo ${SPECIAL_TEXT} > gen1
    )

add_custom_target(
    gen1-wrapper
    DEPENDS gen1
    )
```

gen2 CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT gen2
    DEPENDS gen1-wrapper **????????**
    COMMAND cmake -E copy gen1 gen2
    )

add_custom_target(
    all-generated ALL
    DEPENDS gen2
    )
```

top CMakeList.txt

```
add_subdirectory(gen2)
add_subdirectory(gen1)
```

Is it possible to propagate dependencies without introducing global variables?

Answer (score 1):

The generated files are in a binary directory structure that is the same as the source directory structure, [as per the CMake docs.](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/add_custom_command.html) So you could use a relative path `../gen1/gen1`? I admit that this is not a very robust solution.

An alternative would be to use [object libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/add_library.html?highlight=add_library#object-libraries) `add_library(... OBJECT ...)` and in the top level generator expressions, like so:

`add_executable(... $<TARGET_OBJECTS:gen1> $<TARGET_OBJECTS:gen2>)`.

Comment: Relative paths are not good, they violate principle "Don't assume that your project root is the build root." https://www.slideshare.net/DanielPfeifer1/cmake-48475415

Comment: No, generated files are not objects, so I can't put them in object library.

Comment: I agree with your first comment. Generated files can also be used in object libraries though.

Comment: Interesting, will try

Comment: Ok, I can add object library: `add_library(gen1_lib OBJECT gen1)` . But how can I extract `gen1` path from `gen1_lib`

Comment: I would manage it from the level above. Referencing subfolders of a common ancestor folder leads to maintainability problems quickly (everytime you change something in gen1 you need to change it in gen2 and gen3 and ...).

Comment: Yes, this is what I have to do: managing custom commands in top-level CMake. But referencing siblings is ok in my experience: I have a couple of C++ libraries in git-submodules as a part of CMake tree. And adding link_library(my_target  lib_from_sibling) works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Using cmake v 3.14.2 this works as expected. My specific setup that worked for me:

```
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT gen2
  COMMAND cmake -E copy gen1 gen2
)

add_custom_target(
    all-generated ALL
    DEPENDS gen1-wrapper gen2
)
```